# How to sort a list which holds nested lists, which further holds dictionaries. the aim is to sort the main list by a dictionary VALUE

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am looking to sort a list similar to this using the itemgetter function. I am trying to arrange the list in ascending order by the dictionary KEY "Special number".
Because the nested list deals with dictionaries I am finding this difficult to complete.

```
from operator import itemgetter


lists = [
    [{'time': str, 'ask price': str},
     {'ticker': 'BB','Special number': 10}],
    [{'time': str , 'price': str},
     {'ticker': 'AA', 'Special number': 5}
     ]
]
```

I tried to use:

```
gg = lists.sort(key=itemgetter((1)['special number']))

print(gg)
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: "list would in ascending order"?  "ascending order" of what?

Comment: list item 1 contains  {'Special number': 5}, list item 2 contains {'Special number': 10}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is necessary to use `itemgetter()` here. If the dictionary that has the key `'Special number'` is always in the index 1 of the lists, then it would be enough to do the following:

```
sorted_list = sorted(lists, key=lambda x: x[1]['Special number'])
print(sorted_list)
```

**output**

```
[[{'price': <class 'str'>, 'time': <class 'str'>},
  {'Special number': 5, 'ticker': 'AA'}],
 [{'ask price': <class 'str'>, 'time': <class 'str'>},
  {'Special number': 10, 'ticker': 'BB'}]]
```